# There is an attribute created as ATTR6 when I am displaying that in a separate heading. is that possible

Tags: magento-1.9, attributes

[image: I want to display the highlighted as Brand is that possible? The attributes picked from backend]

I have an attribute created as Attr6 with lot of values. I want to filter the frontend data using the attributes. So when I am trying to displaying the values of the attributes in frontend can I change the heading of it as Brand??

Comment: Which magento version are you using ?

Comment: I am using magento 1.9

Comment: You can change admin "Attr6" attribute Default Label: Brand instead of Attr6

Answer (score 0):

The issue is resolved. There is an option to manage titles when selecting a specific category. It will take default admin value if there are no store specified values are available. Just give the Title you want in the frontend in the field and update the attribute.